# Autosizing UIImageView in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autosize

[image: autosizing]

I am moving a custom UITableViewCell from Interface Builder and into code, but I'm unsure of how to copy the autosizing in the image above.

Would it be `self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);` ?

Comment: The given link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The autosizing clamps to the edges and has flexible height and width so it should be,

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```