# Moving a button in a ViewController from a NSObject class (adjusting to 4" screen)

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, iphone-5

I am working on adjusting all my iPhone screens to the new iPhone 5 4" screen. To make the code easier to manage i would like to use an NSObject class to do this that calls on a ViewController to move a button or whatever needs to be moved.

Would someone please give me some hints how to accomplish this or if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look into using [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html). It will do everything you need.

Comment: Thanks, i have considered that but i need to reposition in more detail and want to do it from NSObject.

Comment: What do you mean by more detail? You can have all the details you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about autoresizing then i am sure the shared link will work
[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)

you can resize your button and view programmatically as well as using interface builder.

Comment: No i am talking of controlling the position of the objects in detail.

Comment: @PeterK may be this [link](http://jamesdempsey.net/2012/10/02/getting-an-app-ready-for-iphone-5/) will be helpful for you.