# Table View's Header with Image is not working in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, tableheader

I am setting Image on Header for TableView in my application.

It's working fine in Iphone 3Gs.But same code not working in Iphone 5.
It just displays frame only with very small size image.

when I increase frame width image not increased.

Here is my code:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        NSLog(@"height%f",result.height);
        if(result.height > 500){
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5");

            UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,30)];
            UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
            if(tableView == tableview1)
                    {
                img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My Contacts Overlay.fw.png"];
                    }
            else if(tableView == tableview2)
                    {
                img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My Contacts Overlay2.fw.png"];
                    }

            [headerView addSubview:img];
            return headerView;
        }
}
```

Can anyone please! help me in this?

Comment: have you set the `heightForHeaderInSection` return the height of your view ?

Comment: @ipatel did u edit my code?

Comment: @user2134883-- yup....why ???

Comment: i do not know where u made change?

Comment: I guess you created this Layout for Retina 3.5 Full Screen(for iPhone 3g) and checking on Retina 4 Full Screen (iPhone 5), both have different size, you can check this in your attribute inspector when you select any Layout (xib) file.

Comment: If u created properties for the two tables use them with self , like self.tableview1, self.tableview2.. some times in some cases it leads a problem also

Answer (score 0):

Set Autoresizingmask for your headerView and img...Hope it ll work

[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)