# How to set frame size for iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, frame, iphone-5, autoresize

I am setting my iphone app screen frames to support iphone 5 , i have set the auto resizing mask [image: mask]  and also i tried by setting the frame programmatically using the following code in `loadview`

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            // iPhone Classic
        }
        if(result.height > 480)
        {
            // iPhone 5
           CGRect mainFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
           self.view.frame = mainFrame;
        }
    }
```

but it didnt work [image: didn't work] ,

can any one tell me how do i set the frame , thanx in advance

Comment: do you have Default-568h@2x.png in project?

Comment: NO, i have not added splash image

Comment: is your application universal?

Comment: @RaviKiran Have you checked my code. Is it working for you ?

Comment: ya i have added Default-568h@2x.png,,and it worked fine

Comment: How to add Default-568h@2x.png >? @Ravi Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to check :

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

So

```
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
 // Iphone 5 frame
}
else
{
// iphone 4 frame

}
```

and add `Default-568h@2x.png` in your project also.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: How to add Default-568h@2x.png in my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for one of the below reason

1) If you rotate device , check your main screen bounds. It may lead to confusion. You can try Better way to use it.

2) This `Default-568h.png` is only allowed when building an app using Xcode 4.5 and the iOS 6 SDK

3) When you ask a `UIScreen` for it's Bounds you get the bounds of the screen, which is the whole device screen. (the status bar is part of the screen)

So It may get `false` two `if` conditions.

You can use this code ..

```
-(BOOL)isDeviceGreaterThaniPhone5
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) {// @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
        return YES;
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]) {// @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
        return YES;
    }
    else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]){ // @"iPod touch 5G";
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Don't forget to import `#import <sys/utsname.h>`

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
if ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ) {

//iphone5 frame

}
else{
//not an iphone5 frame
}
```

for details [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Response from Nishant is great, Here I am just providing a consized version of this, as you know height is only difference, hence pass height for your frame in both conditions:

Here is a macro:

```
#define ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular, longScreen) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : longScreen)
```

And Here how to use it:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(460, 548));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you should add your view as subview and wait until it will be drawn.

For my project I solved this by putting a code which depends on screen size after autosizing into drawRect: for UIViews and into viewDidAppear for UIViewControllers.

So if you use a correct autoresizing mask then you may not make your view longer:
[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)