# a UIView scaled with animateWithDuration doesn't scale its subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIView that contains two `UIImageView`s.
when I perform `animateWithDuration` and change its frame (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`) , it's `subviews` aren't resized according to its frame.

How can this be done? is it something with `contentMode` of the `superview` or `subviews`?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the subviews auto-resizing rules. If you don't specify any rules the subviews will maintain their size and position (relative to the top left corner).

Check the auto-resizing documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW15). That's the 'simple' version which works from before iOS 6. From iOS 6 onwards you can also use auto-layout which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html).

Comment: thanks, the documentation link led me to the autoresizemask property, but this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib really helped me because it explains how to do it in IB.