# Layout for iPhone5 vs iPhone4

Tags: iphone, layout, ios6, uiview

In iPhone5 storyboard main view controller view, I have a dragged UIControls like UIButtons and others. The controls fill out the whole space all the way to bottom of the screen. Well, on the iPhone 4 obviously the bottom portion of my view won't show due to smaller screen. What is the right way to handle this so it shows on both devices correctly?

Comment: you have problem on iphone 4 because control fill out whole page im rite ? can you explain more detail?

Comment: Let's say I dragged 10 buttons and placed them vertically in the storyboard. The first button at the very top of the screen and the bottom is at the bottom of the screen on the iPhone5. In the iPhone 4, this same UI will be cut off and show may be the top 7 buttons.

Comment: for iphone 4 size is 320x460 but for iphone 5 size is 320x568 .so it will reduce your screen size.
you design it in scroll view and then use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem with View ResizingMask. You have to set `autoResizingMask`.

You can refer to this [AutoResizingMask Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)

This will help you alot. Try to set the `autoResizingMask` of control through xib. Sure you will get rid of your problem..!! Enjoy Coding

Comment: Is this answer related with autolayout?

Comment: No I dont think so that you need to use autoResizeingMask while using Autolayout Structure. I am not pretty much aware of this because I didnot ever implement it.

Comment: Sorry man... I confused the word "Layout" in title with "Autolayout".