# Shrink and expand the uiview according to the scrollview content offset

Tags: ios, uiview

hi in my app I want to implement animation like instagram navigationBar animation.. I done all the thing.. I shrink and expand the headerView according to the UITableview contentOffset.. it shrink well with its subview well but while expand the headerView the subview **height** and the **y** position changed..

```
 headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? 64 : 44))];
        UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:headerView.bounds];
        view1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        view1.alpha = 0.1;
        [headerView addSubview:view1];

    headerView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

//UIImageView..

```
    headerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320 - 190) / 2 , (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? 28 : 8), 190, 28)]; 
    headerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]; 
    headerImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    headerImageView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [headerView addSubview:headerImageView];
```

//Back button

```
backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        backButton.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [backButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"listLeftMenu.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton setFrame: CGRectMake(10, (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? 34 : 14), 18, 16)]; 

        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftMenuAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [headerView addSubview:backButton];

        [self.view addSubview:headerView];
```

Above code is my headerView initialization...

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{


    CGFloat height = (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? 64 : 44) - scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (height < 0) {
        height = 0;
    }
    [headerView positionAtX:0  andY:0 withHeight:height]; // This is I change the x, y and height of the headerview..

    [postTable positionAtY:height];
}
```

I know miss anything to keep the subview frame while expand... please help me to fix this issue...

Comment: This can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib

Comment: @βhargavḯ:I create all subview Programatically..

Comment: yes I know just look at the Sam's answer.

Comment: @βhargavḯ: I use that but didn't get my exact solution.. Big thanks for your soon response