# How do I programmatically snap a UIPickerView to the bottom of the parent view it resides in, in iOS 7/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uipickerview

So I have UICollectionViewController and have added a UIPickerView to controllers view. Right now the UIPickerView sits beneath the nav bar.

How do I make it automatically take the bounds of the view it's within, whether on an iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 and use this to snap the UIPickerView to the bottom of it's parent.

Regards

Comment: When you add the picker this way, does it scroll with the collection view?

Comment: @rdelmar The picker doesn't scroll with the collectionView. I added it to view instead of collectionView which is connected to my actual collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What worked in the end was:**

```
CGFloat viewHeight = [[self view] frame].size.height;
CGFloat pickerHeight;

UIPickerView *filterPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerHeight = [filterPicker frame].size.height;
[filterPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewHeight - pickerHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, pickerHeight)];
[[self view] addSubview:filterPicker];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into struts and springs for the picker view.  This has been covered a lot on stackoverflow.

[autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)

Comment: I came across this during my search and it didn't work for me. I used filterPicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin; and it never worked for me.

Comment: if you set the masks in code, are you also triggering a layout update.  I read somewhere that it only works when the view gets laid out again?