# Adjusting the frame of all the controls for all the iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have code project written on xcode 5.1. I have set the frames of all the controls which is working fine with iPhone 5 and later. But when I run the same project on iPhone 4s, the frames I have adjusted is not fitting to the screen of iPhone 4s. Please could someone help me with the easy solution of how to adjust the frame of all controls. Will I need to manually change the frame of all the controls?

Comment: you should use autolayout or autoresizing.

Comment: Please explain me how can I use autolayout or autoresizing

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple xib/storyboard one for iphone5 screen size and another one for iphone4 screen size

and then make changes in appDelegate like this

// if use story board

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     UIStoryboard *storyBord;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   {
         if(self.window.frame.size.height == 568)
             storyBord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        else
             storyBord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone4" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   }
   self.window.rootViewController = [storyBord instantiateInitialViewController];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

// if you are using .xib files then each view controller.m file you have to init like this

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"FeedActivity_iPhone5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        else
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"FeedActivity_iPhone4" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
}
return self;
}
```

You can also go with Use auto layout but it seems this goes easy for you

Comment: I am not using storyboard while I am using only xib files

Comment: @AnandK is it good idea to create multiple xib. why are you not suggesting autolayout or autoresizing?

Comment: Because he seems very confused and this is easy way to do

Answer (score 0):

[image]

mainly it depends on your requirement, but still setting this autoresizing mask to your element will help you.

[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)

Answer (score 0):

You can use autolayout. To do it so, you first check if the storyboard has autolayout checked

[image: autolayout]

Then, you need add the constraints

[image: constrains]

I recommend you to check this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo