# using NSAutolayout concept how to display button all versions at same place in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Hi i am creating button programatically. And i am working some app in ios6&ios7 4-inches screen and 3.5 inches screen. I need to display the button for all versions at same position.

So i want to use Auto layout concept for this.i know how to create button programatically, but I have no idea about how to apply auto layout concept for button. This is my code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

    [self.view addConstraints:@[

                                //view1 constraints
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:padding.top],

                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:padding.left],

                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:-padding.bottom],

                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                            multiplier:1
                                                              constant:-padding.right],

                                ]];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Update:

```
button.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

Ref.Link: [Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib)

Comment: thanks for your response.If i create another button same procedure is going on?

Comment: bro it is working fine bro.But u are again updated answer na?so which one can i use it.And another question is if i create another button same procedure i will follow?

Comment: check both answer, use which one is perfect to u. And, you have to use this for all

Comment: but for second you have to use suitable autoresizingmask, pls check attached link , you ll know

Comment: If your question got satisfied answer, please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you
Visit https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry