# how to give fixed bottom margin using autosizing mask ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm new to autoresizing mask in ios,I want to fix a button to fixed bottom margin,in the interface builder it was easy but programatically unable to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interfact-builder-xib-nib check this

Comment: i have gone through the post before ididnt understand that,thanks