# iOS: Autosizing not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I am making a very simple app to learn Objective-C and Xcode. The app has an UIButton and a UIImageView. When the user taps the button the image moves down in a diagonal motion from right to left and when it reaches a certain point in the screen it regenerates back to do the same all over again as shown in the image below:

(Using an 'if statement')

[image]

When I open the iOS simulator using iPhone Retina (4-inch) it works perfectly fine.
The problem is when I open the simulator using iPhone Retina (3.5 inch):

[image]

It loads the image and everything seems fine, I press the button until the image reaches point B but when it regenerates back this is what happens:

[image]

The image moved down.I have no clue why it does this. I been searching for an answer all day long but nothing seems to work. I have the Auto Layout box unchecked and autosizing like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

File.h

```
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageOne;

}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;

@end
```

File.m

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{    

//ImageOne moving down and reappearing

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                 animations:^{

                     imageOne.center = CGPointMake(imageOne.center.x -44, imageOne.center.y +41);

                 }];

if (imageOne.center.x < -28) {
    imageOne.center = CGPointMake(368,487);

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Autosizing an UIImage programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519226/ios-autosizing-an-uiimage-programmatically)

Comment: There is no answer that has helped me with my problem in that question. So, instead of saying possible duplicate will you help me out?

Comment: Try to add constraints  for your UIImageview

Comment: I have auto layout unchecked

Comment: I see in Autosizing that you pinned the image to the bottom. Can you remove that, or try using both top and bottom pinning to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Yes it makes a difference, when i remove the bottom one and i open the 3.5 inch simulator it show the image way up in the screen, and when it reaches point B, the image goes back to the problem. So that isn't the answer :(

Comment: It looks like autosizing doesn't happen when the image regenerates back. It just works until the image reaches point B

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{    

   CGPoint startingPoint = CGPointMake(startingXPoint, startingYPoint);
   CGPoint destinationPoint = CGPointMake(destinationXPoint, destinationYPoint);
   imageOne.center = startingPoint;



   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f  animations:^{

            imageOne.center = destinationPoint;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

            imageOne.center = startingPoint;

        }];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... My problem is that when the image reaches point B the setting that i have for autosizing doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to set an if statement that says: if (is iPhone (3.5 inch)) { imageOne.center = CGPointMake(other_x_value, other_y_value } else { imageOne.center =CGPointMake (368,487);

Comment: setting that you have for autosizing? not sure what you mean. This works for me so something in your settings is causing the issue