# How to make this xib file fill the entire screen of iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I would like to use the same nib file for both iPad and iPhone.

I found there are two black bars in the top and bottom when I run the app on iPhone 6 plus. So I found there is a fixed size defined in my xib file, and they are **not editable**.

How should I make it adapt to different screen size?

Note: 
* The project doesn't use **autolayout** and **storyboard**

[image]

Comment: Enable Vertical Arrow which inside the square, showing in your image..surly this was working..

Answer (score 5):

On `viewWillAppear` set frame of your xib file.

## swift

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
```

## Objective-C

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self view] setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around it, you need to use autolayout and size classes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

You can use nib files, that's fine, but autolayout and size classes are unavoidable if you're going to make an app for all devices.

Comment: Incorrect. If your nib is for iPhone, you will always have black lines around it and it will never be universal. If you want your app to be universal, you have to use autolayout and size classes. Otherwise, you need multiple nibs for multiple devices. And yes a very bad UX and costly code base to maintain.

Comment: No, Without AutoLayout and size classes Universal application will be possible..U have to use Autoresizing..and active all the resizable arrow... this was working for me..

Answer (score -2):

[image: AutoResizing Image]

You have to unable all the Auto Resizing masks at XIB

In ur picture, u also need to set **Width & Height Auto Resizing masks**..So that the xib/view will take the width & Height as per super view or fill the screen.

For more info about Auto Resizing Masks refer below link..

[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interface-builder-xib-nib)

Hope it helps you..

Comment: See my comment answering your incorrect comment (deleted comment?)

Comment: I will also suggest AutoLayouts to support for all devices as Apple Recommended..but If u don't want to use it then go for AutoResizing masks..I would prefer AutoLayouts only...

Comment: To be clear, autosizing masks requires you to have a nib for iPhone and a nib for iPad. OP specifically said "I would like to use the same nib file for both iPad and iPhone". The only way to achieve this is to use autolayout and size classes.