# Change imageview height programmatically ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have this kind of structure in storyboard:

```
UIViewController > View > Scrollview > Scrollview > UIImageview
```

By Default imageview size is : 320x230. Check below image:

[image]

Now i need to change size of that imageview Programmatically.

Lets say i need to set frame : 320x280

Autolayout is disabled see image:

[image]

**Here is what i have done:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imgThumbnail.frame = (frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.result.width, 280))
}
```

But its not working at all. Its not changing size of imageview. One more important thing is when i scroll down & up the scrollview. It takes the new frame which i have set in above code in imageview.

It will be great if someone guide me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is self.result.width?

Comment: @NSNoob         result = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set imageView Autoresizing Property to None and height to required height as follows:-

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = .None
imageView.frame.size.height = 280.0
```

To better understand Autoresizing Masks refer this link :-
[Autoresizing masks programmatically vs Interface Builder / xib / nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interface-builder-xib-nib)